# mysql database update and codeigniter rows affected function

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using this function this codeigniter function after update query

```
$this->db->affected_rows();
```

it returns number of rows affected if i update values, but if i update values with the same as previous it retuns 0 rows affected

Any help...

Comment: You get 0 rows affected the 2nd time you run the same query? I would think this was the right behavior since there is nothing to change when you run the same query for the 2nd time. What is the problem you're having?

Comment: yes i understand what i need is the confirmation that query has successfully run.

Answer (score 7):

> yes i understand what i need is the confirmation that query has successfully run.

All CI database functions return a result if they "successfully run".

So

```
$result = $this->db->update('your_table', $data);
if ( ! $result)
{
     // Error
}
{
     // Function ran ok - do whatever
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to check that the database query succeeded, you can check the error code by using:

```
$this->db->_error_message();
```

If that is empty, you had no error.   If not, you have the error message. `_error_number()` is also set, so you can use that instead if you are looking for a particular error.

Generally, you can skip the error check if you know there were `affected_rows()`, so you can limit the `_error_message()` test to situations where `affected_rows()` returns 0.